# Touchpad right click doesn't work on HP Envy 14 beats

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, hp

I have Ubuntu 12.04 lts 64 bits on my HP envy 14 beats. When I try to click with the right click button it doesn't work. Only works click in the touchpad directly and with usb mouse.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0105] (rev 09)
00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0109] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 [8086:1c1e] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series] [1002:6741]
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:4238] (rev 3e)
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
0b:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
```

Answer (score 1):

create a folder called /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

and then name the below as 51.clickpad.conf:

Section "InputClass"

Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"

MatchDriver "synaptics"

Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"

EndSection

then log out and log back in again

you could always read the Ubuntu Documentation or Touchpad Synaptics WiKi; links provided below

if your touchpad is not recognised by ubuntu; you can check this by using synclient and seeing if Clickpad=0, if so then you can do 1 of 2 things:

add the following to the above 51.clickpad.conf:

Option "ClickPad"         "true"

Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"

or

use the following and create a shell script, make it exectuable and run it at start up

sleep 3

synclient Clickpad=1

end

:)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-touchpad-click.html

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 fingers to right click. Instead of tapping the touchpad with one finger use 2 fingers. I hope this helps cause it worked on my Dv7t Beats Edition.

Comment: how i do that? push the right click with the two fingers?